# Trouble with Set.forall F#

Tags: f#

I'm having trouble trying to compare an element to all elements of a set. I want to write a boolean function that returns true if an element is not a neighbour and false if an element is a neighbour.  We want to colour the chart
so that two countries that share a border are not given the same colour. I will explain it with code

```
type Country = string;;
type Chart = Set<Country*Country>;;
type Colour = Set<Country>;;
type Colouring = Set<Colour>;;

(* This is how you tell that two countries are neighbours.  It requires a chart.*)
let areNeighbours ct1 ct2 chart =
  Set.contains (ct1,ct2) chart || Set.contains (ct2,ct1) chart;;
(* val areNeighbours :
  ct1:'a -> ct2:'a -> chart:Set<'a * 'a> -> bool when 'a : comparison
  *)
```

I'm having trouble with the canBeExtBy function. If this is my chart and my col:

```
val myWorld : Chart =
  set
    [("Andorra", "Benin"); ("Andorra", "Canada"); ("Andorra", "Denmark");
     ("Benin", "Canada"); ("Benin", "Denmark"); ("Canada", "Denmark");
     ("Estonia", "Canada"); ("Estonia", "Denmark"); ("Estonia", "Finland");
     ...]

col = set 
    ["Canada"]
```

then my function should return false if I call

```
canBeExtBy col "Denmark" myWorld;;
```

Here is my code, I get an error which is listed at the bottom.

```
(* The colour col can be extended by the country ct when they are no neighbours
according to chart.*)

       val canBeExtBy :
      col:Set<'a> -> ct:'a -> chart:Set<'a * 'a> -> bool when 'a : comparison
    *)
```

Error:

```
 Set.forall(fun x -> areNeighbours x ct) col;;
  ----------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
This expression was expected to have type
    bool    
but here has type
    Set<'a * 'a> -> bool
```

Comment: Your `areNeighbours` function requires three arguments, but you're passing only two (`x` and `ct`) in the lambda.

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev You should post this as an answer :)

Comment: Similar question: [What am I doing wrong with Set.Fold F#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35276324/1243762)

Comment: Out of curiosity are you a CS student at McGill?

Answer (score 2):

Listen to your types.

```
This expression was expected to have type
    bool    
but here has type
    Set<'a * 'a> -> bool
```

Instead of a boolean value, there is a function of type `Set<'a * 'b> -> bool`. That is a sign for a partially applied function that's missing its last argument of type `Set<'a * 'b>`. If you look at your `areNeighbours` function, you can see that it takes three arguments, two of type `Country`, and one of type `Chart`, but in `canBeExtBy`, you're only passing it two `Country` values, but not the `Chart`.

To make it compile, `canBeExtBy` needs to look like this:

```
let canBeExtBy col ct chart =
    Set.forall(fun x -> areNeighbours x ct chart |> not) col
```